# Get array element and remove

Tags: ios, swift

I've array with several elements, I want to generate a random element from that array and after generating I want to remove that element. I tried `remove` method but it returns an error `Cannot find 'randSachmeli' in scope` `randSachmeli` is a random generated array

```swift
struct SachmelebiData {
    let name:String
    let link:String
}

var mainMenu:[SachmelebiData] = [
    SachmelebiData(name: "ხინკალი", link: ""),
    SachmelebiData(name: "მწვადი", link: ""),
    SachmelebiData(name: "yleyveri", link: "")
]
let yvelaSachmeli:[SachmelebiData] = mainMenu

        var randSachemli = yvelaSachmeli.randomElement()
        yvelaSachmeli.remove(randSachmeli)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get random elements from the index by getting random index from array indices. And then delete the element by index.

```
var yvelaSachmeli:[SachmelebiData] = mainMenu

// Get the random element from the array
guard let randomIndexFromArray = yvelaSachmeli.indices.randomElement() else {
    return
}
// Get the element from the index
var randSachemli = yvelaSachmeli[randomIndexFromArray]

// Remove the element by index
yvelaSachmeli.remove(at: randomIndexFromArray)
```

Comment: Hint: `remove(at:)` returns a value, which you are ignoring...